# Can MIN and ISBLANK be used together in a calculated column?

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a custom list that displays the expiry date of Certificate 1 and Certificate 2. Candidates must have both to be considered Certified. The Certification expiry date is the earlier of the two certificates so I use the following formula

```
=MIN([Certificate 1 expiry date],[Certificate 2 expiry date])
```

This works fine until somebody doesn't have an expiry date for one of the certificates and then the Certification Expiry Date is 30/12/1899.

How do I get the Certification Expiry Date to be blank if they are missing one of the certificates?

I asked a similer question on Stack Overflow and I was given the following formula that works in Excel but not in SharePoint? Can MIN and ISBLANK be used together in a calculated column?

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(Certificate 1 expiry date),ISBLANK(Certificate 2 expiry date)),"",MIN(Certificate 1 expiry date,Certificate 2 expiry date))
```

Comment: SharePoint 2007, 2010 or 2013 ?

Comment: SharePoint 2007

Answer (score 1):

I used this formula in WSS 3.0 (12.0.0.6690) and it worked.

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(date1),ISBLANK(date2)),"",MIN(date1,date2))
```

[image]

Check for your separtors if you use a different regional setting than English.